# VBA: Search email in non default outlook inbox?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am using the following VBA code which checks for any emails with a specific subject heading.

The problem is it checks my default outlook inbox folder when I need it to check the inbox of my other email account.

Can someone please show me how I would do this?

```
Sub Macro1()
   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

       Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
       Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
       Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
       Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
       Dim I As Long
       Dim olMail As Variant


       Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
       Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
       Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
       Set myTasks = Fldr.Items


    Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""New Supplier Request: Ticket""")
    If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then



      For Each myItem In myTasks
          If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
              For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
              If InStr(myAttachment.DisplayName, ".txt") Then
                  I = I + 1
                  myAttachment.SaveAsFile "\\uksh000-file06\Purchasing\NS\Unactioned\" & myAttachment
                  End If
              Next
          End If

      Next



  For Each myItem In myTasks
  myItem.Delete
  Next

  Call Macro2

  Else
  MsgBox "There Are No New Supplier Requests."
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have declared variable myItem as Outlook.MailItem and you use it later to iterate through the collection of items in MAPI folder.

However, MAPI folder contains not only MailItems but also MeetingItems and every time the loop finds an object of MeetingItem type, it throws an Mismatch type error since it expects only objects of MailItem type.

You just need to change declaration of myItem variable to:

```
Dim myItem as Object
```

=============================================================

The code below should iterate through the filtered items only:

```
Sub Work_with_Outlook()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim i As Long



    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items



    Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""test""")
    While Not olMail Is Nothing

        If olMail.Attachments.Count Then

            For Each myAttachment In olMail.Attachments
                i = i + 1
                myAttachment.SaveAsFile "\\uksh000-file06\Purchasing\Supplier Attachments\test" & i & ".txt"
            Next myAttachment

        End If

        Set olMail = myTasks.FindNext

    Wend

    MsgBox "Scan Complete."

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however when I do this the macro just seems to take forever to do anything and never actually does anything, I've waited upto 10 minutes with just the cursor egg timer showing?

Comment: In fact, your code downloads attachments from all the e-mails in your mailbox, not only from the one with subject _test_. You have found item with this subject and assign it to the variable olMail, but I can't see where you refer to this variable later in the code. Instead, you use again myTasks variable in your loop and this variable is the collection of all e-mails.

Comment: any idea how I can just download the attachment for the email with the subject test? Bearing in mind there may be several emails with the subject test, how could I then save each attachment into a random different folder? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my post to include the code for processing filtered items only instead of all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through all folder items in Outlook:

```
 For Each myItem In myTasks
    If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
```

I'd suggest using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class. Also you may consider using using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class. Take a look at the following articles for the sample code which illustrates how to use them in the code:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)